# semi page curl animation background view color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my project I'm using page animation.
My problem is that I want to show red colour on the background of curled view. How do I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self]; [animation setDuration:0.75];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
animation.type = @"pageUnCurl"; 
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
animation.startProgress = 0.65; 
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:[self.view.subviews count]-2 withSubviewAtIndex:3];
[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:[self.view.subviews count]-3 withSubviewAtIndex:2];
[[[self view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

This is how I change my view.

Comment: add 2 views and use the view beneath to add buttons...

Comment: Paste a code here. We don't know what methods to curl up did you used. Probably you should add this view into some other view and set background color, but this is a only lucky guess without code.

Comment: Perhaps set the backgroundcolor of your mainWindow?

Comment: i had done that one also but there is no change in that view .

Comment: Does the answer that Siddharth added help? If so, please accept that answer. It helps clean up the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you use CALayer as the background page when animation is happening.

```
topPageReverseOverlay = [[CALayer alloc] init];
topPageReverseOverlay.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using layers then when app going to background process then you can loose the curl effect of that particular layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want complete control over the display of what's behind a partial curl, you can set it as a separate VC. Here's an example:

```
EndPartialCurlViewController *nextViewController = [[EndPartialCurlViewController alloc] init];
[nextViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[[self navigationController] presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can then build any  color, views, buttons, etc. you want into this EndPartialCurlViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer for your question can be found in this thread..
[Underside color of curling view using UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019501/underside-color-of-curling-view-using-uiviewanimationtransitioncurlup)

Answer (score 0):

after lot of surfing i found that there is one way by using filters and layes we can achieve this one but that one undocumented method and  If you are using layers then when app going to background process then you can loose the curl effect of that particular layer..